# SignalR Silverlight Client keeps "connected", when Hub is disconnected

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have implemented SignalR in my Silverlight 5 application and it's working fine as long as the client stays on-line. But as soon as the network connection drops for more than about 5 seconds, it stops functioning and I can't make it reconnect.

When a client loses the network connection, the Hub's event "OnDisconnected" is triggered.
But on the client side the HubConnection's *Closed* or *StateChanged* events are not triggered and the ConnectionState remains **Connected**. It then tries to make a call to hubproxy.Invoke(), but that will not invoke the client-side method as it would if the network connection stayed alive.

I instantiate the signalr client in App.xaml.xs:

```
private void Application_UserLoaded(LoadUserOperation operation)
{
 //Some checks whether user is logged in
  _signalRClient = new SignalRClient();
  _signalRClient.RunAsync();
}
```

.

```
public class SignalRClient
{
  public async void RunAsync()
  {
    SetHubConnection();

    SetHubProxy();

    await StartHubConnection();

    SendTestSignal();
  }

  private void SetHubConnection()
  {
  try
  {
    _hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://10.1.2.3/HubWeb");
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    LoggerManager.WriteLog(LogType.ERROR, ex.ToString());
  }

  _hubConnection.Closed += () => TimeoutHelper.SetTimeout(5000, () => _hubConnection.Start());
  _hubConnection.StateChanged += (change) => LoggerManager.WriteLog(LogType.DEBUG, String.Format("SignalR Client:    Connection State Changed from {0} to {1}", change.OldState, change.NewState));

}
```

I tried to implement automatic reconnect, as the documentation suggests, by handling the client side *Closed* event and that starting the hubconnection. 
But because the ConnectionState is still "Connected", this event is not triggered and I do not see a way to restart the connection from the client.
What could be the cause of the Connectionstate property of client's hubconnection not changing tot "Disconnected" and why is the *Closed* event not triggered?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well using the .net SignalR client - my closed() event never fires. Have you learned anything new?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You could check the ConnectionState Property periodically, if that does change. But because that stays 'Connected' as well I ended up invoking the hubproxy first with a separate call, just to verify the connection. I store a DateTime.Now in a member of SignalR Client if this method gets invoked, so I can compare that moment in time to the actual moment. If the stored moment is too long ago, I stop and start the hubconnection manually.